# Why do I get inverted colors in my images?

Tags: ros, libopencv, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am fetching images from a camera/webcam and publishing it's images using `image_transport`.
When viewed in RViz the images look correct however when recorded with rosbag the `compressed` image shows inverted colors.

Here is the node to record the images:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

int main(int argc,
         char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Publisher pub = it.advertise("camera", 1);

  cv::VideoCapture cap;
  if (!cap.open(0))
    return 1;

  ros::Rate loop_rate(25);
  while (nh.ok())
  {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
      break;

    sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", frame).toImageMsg();
    pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Minimal example package:
https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/image_transport_test

## RViz

[image: RViz]

## rqt_bag

[image: rqt_bag]

Why are the colors inverted in the compressed image when reading the bag file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276180/why-do-i-get-inverted-colors-in-my-images?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CesarHoyosM](https://answers.ros.org/users/30733/cesarhoyosm/) on 2017-11-17**:
Hello there! Are you sure your format to output these images is "bgr8" and not "rgb8"? This is a typical issue because how openCV handles images, inverting order of input channels of colors. I am not but you can try and give us feedback.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-11-20**:
@CesarHoyosM I think so while not being 100% sure. If I use `rgb8` then the colors are inverted in RViz and in the `raw` image in the bag file, but then the `compressed` image has the right colors. In short: this inverts the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am most probably missing a point, either I am not using `image_transport` properly or there is a bug in the `image_transport` package.

The best alternative I have found now is the following one:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

int main(int argc,
         char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_publisher");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  std::string publish_topic("/webcam");
  ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Image>(publish_topic, 5);
  ros::Publisher c_pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::CompressedImage>(publish_topic + "/compressed", 5);

  cv::VideoCapture cap;
  if (!cap.open(0))
    return 1;

  ros::Rate loop_rate(25);
  while (nh.ok())
  {
    cv::Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    if (frame.empty())
      continue;

    sensor_msgs::ImagePtr msg = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "bgr8", frame).toImageMsg();
    sensor_msgs::CompressedImagePtr c_msg =
        cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "rgb8", frame).toCompressedImageMsg();

    pub.publish(msg);
    c_pub.publish(c_msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I set two publishers: one for the raw image (`bgr8` encoding) and one for the compressed image (`rgb8` encoding)
This way I get both the JPEG compressed images and the raw image with decent performance and the right colors.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2017-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-11-27**:
I will not mark this answer as correct as this is only a "good alternative", it does not answer the question.